# Split a string, after every 2 decimal place, with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following string:

```
12.0024.0024.0024.0036.0012.0012.0012.004.006.008.004.004.0012.0012.0012.00
```

I want to create an array that is split after 2 decimal place, that should look something like this, if I were to instantiate it:

```
var numArray = new Array ('12.00', '24.00', '24.00', '24.00', '36.00', '12.00', '12.00', '12.00', '4.00', '6.00', '8.00', '4.00', '4.00', '12.00', '12.00', '12.00')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *might* be able to split the input string at the interface between a non zero digit on the left and a zero digit on the right:

```js
var input = "12.0024.0024.0024.0036.0012.0012.0012.004.006.008.004.004.0012.0012.0012.00";
var nums = input.split(/(?<=0)(?=[^\D0])/);
console.log(nums);
```

But, this only coincidentally works here because every float number in the string happens to end with trailing zeroes.  If that were not the case, the above method would fail.  A better approach would be to manage your data better and not work with such cryptic number strings.

Comment: The regex can just be `/(?<=\...)/`, then it doesn't have to be a zero

Comment: @Wyck I don't understand your suggestion, because you have an ellipsis `...` in place of something else.  Your suggestion looks wrong to me, however.

Comment: It's not an ellipsis.  `\.` matches a literal `.` (the decimal point) and the two `.`'s after that each match any character, thus absorbing two characters after a decimal place. The rest is a lookbehind assertion. I admit it does look like an ellipsis. I didn't invent the syntax though.   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯